# fastest way to get the checked radio button using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I wanted to get the selected radio button and display the text that corresponds the radio button using jquery.

```
<div id="Poll">
    <div id="PollQuestion">Your favorite color?</div>
    <ul>
        <li class="liAnswer">
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="Answer" class="clsAnswer"/>
            <span>Red</span>
        </li>
        <li class="liAnswer">
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="Answer" class="clsAnswer"/>
            <span>Blue</span>
        </li>
        <li class="liAnswer">
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="Answer" class="clsAnswer"/>
            <span>Green</span>
        </li>
        <li class="liAnswer">
            <input type="radio" value="4" name="Answer" class="clsAnswer"/>
            <span>Yellow</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="button" value="Submit Vote" id="btnVote"/>
</div>
```

First, check if there is no selected color and then display the selected color and the corresponding value.

How can I do that?

Here is my code in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/LhFPD/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[working solution here](http://jsfiddle.net/LhFPD/2/)

```
$("#btnVote").click(function(){
    var selected = $(".clsAnswer:checked");
    if(!selected.val()){
        alert('No color selected!')
    }
    else{
        var selectedValue = selected.val();
        var selectedName = selected.siblings().text();
        alert("Color: " + selectedName + "\r\nValue: " + selectedValue );
    }
});
```

Solves the problem :)

Answer (score 7):

`$('#Poll :radio:checked').val()`

http://jsfiddle.net/LhFPD/5/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btnVote').click(function() {
    var x = $('ul').find('input:checked');
    alert(x.val() + ' ' + x.next().text());
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/wWYzY/

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
  $("#btnVote").click(function() {
    var radioButton = $('#Poll :checked');

    if (!radioButton.val()) {
         alert('No color selected!')
    }
    else {
        var selectedColor = $('.clsAnswer :checked ~ span').html();
        var selectedValue = $('.clsAnswer :checked').val();

        alert("Color: " + selectedColor + "; Value: " + selectedValue);
    }
});
```